# Problem validating dynamically added fieldset using unobtrusive validation

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently working on a site that needs to dynamically add views/change views based on user input.  Depending on what the user selects in a drop-down box, I render a partial view on the page.  For most of the views, this works; however, I have one partial view that has the option to generate multiple field-sets. Unobtrusive validation works when there is only one field-set (read: the user does not select the option to add more), but when the user generates more field-sets, validation only fires for the first set.  After looking around here for a bit, I found Xhalent's post regarding dynamic unobtrusive validation, as well as a post that gave me the logic to actually duplicate the field-set.  Unfortunately, I am pretty new (bad) at JS/jQuery, and have yet to figure out how to get the two ideas to mesh well.

Here is the jQuery code I use to duplicate the form fields (I did not include the actual fields because this is really a conceptual problem, and what the fields are is irrelevant at this point. Plus I don't really understand how to format them here):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#itemCountSec1").change(function () {
        var itemCountVal = jQuery(this).val();
        $("#Section1Fields").fieldsManage(itemCountVal);

    });
});
```

(NOTE: itemCountVal is a user-selected number 1-6)

Here is the function that I have saved in a JS file (Dupe.js):

```
jQuery.fn.fieldsManage = function (number) {
var ele = $(this);
var clones = ele.data("clones");
clones = clones ? clones : new Array(ele.attr("id"));
if (clones.length < number) {
    var clone;
    while (clones.length < number) {
        clone = ele.clone(true);
        var id = clones[0] + clones.length;
        clone.attr("id", id);
        $("#" + clones[clones.length - 1]).after(clone);
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent(clone);
        clones.push(id);
        clone.find("input").each(function () { jQuery(this).val("") });
    }
} else {
    while (clones.length > number) {
        $("#" + clones.pop()).remove();
    }
}
ele.data("clones", clones);
```

}

Here is Xhalent's modified unobtrusive JS code, which i saved in another JS file (validex.js):

```
(function ($) {
$.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent = function (selector) {
    //use the normal unobstrusive.parse method
    $jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse(selector);
    //get the relevant form
    var form = $(selector).first().closest('form');
    //get the collections of unobstrusive validators, and jquery validators
    //and compare the two
    var unobtrusiveValidation = form.data('unobtrusiveValidation');
    var validator = form.validate();
    $.each(unobtrusiveValidation.options.rules, function (elname, elrules) {
        if (validator.settings.rules[elname] == undefined) {
            var args = {};
            $.extend(args, elrules);
            args.messages = unobtrusiveValidation.options.messages[elname];
            //edit:use quoted strings for the name selector
            $("[name='" + elname + "']").rules("add", args);

        } else {
            $.each(elrules, function (rulename, data) {
                if (validator.settings.rules[elname][rulename] == undefined) {
                    var args = {};
                    args[rulename] = data;
                    args.messages = unobtrusiveValidation.options.messages[elname][rulename];
                    //edit:use quoted strings for the name selector
                    $("[name='" + elname + "']").rules("add", args);
                }
            });
        }
    });
} })($);
```

I know that this:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent('form input:last');
```

Or some variant of this, has to go somewhere, but I am at a loss.

The question:  How can I incorporate Xhalent's fine validation method into my code that duplicates the fieldset?

EDIT:

Here are the scripts referenced on the page (Section 1.cshtml):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Dupe.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is the form to be duplicated:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Section1","P15",FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
<legend>FILL ME OUT FIRST!</legend>
    <div class="PrimaryOPSelector">
        OP Number (This is your Primary OP, or the OP that you would be changing shifts from):
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OP_Number, new SelectList(Model.Ops, "Op_Number", "Op_Number"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OP_Number)
    </div>
<p>Please select the number of shifts you would like to have off/change with another staff member: <select id="itemCountSec1" name="itemCountSec1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select></p>
<div class="ReasonForRequest">
        Please Select The Reson For Your Request For Time Off:
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Reason_For_Request, new SelectList(Model.ReasonsForRequest, "Reason_ID", "Reason_For_Request1"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reason_For_Request)
    </div>
</fieldset>  
<fieldset id="Section1Fields">

       <p><strong>Shift Start Date: </strong>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Month, new SelectList(Model.Months, "Month_Value", "Month_Name"))
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Day, new SelectList(Model.Days))
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, new SelectList(Model.Years))</p>

<p><strong>Start Time Of Shift: </strong>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.Start_Hour, new SelectList(Model.Hours)) :
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Start_Min, new SelectList(Model.Minutes))
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Start_Marker, new SelectList(Model.AMPM))
</p>


<p><strong>End Time Of Shift: </strong>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.End_Hour, new SelectList(Model.Hours)) :  
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.End_Min, new SelectList(Model.Minutes))
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.End_Marker, new SelectList(Model.AMPM))
</p>


<p><strong>Covering Staff Employee Number: </strong>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Covering_Staff_Employee_Num)</p>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Covering_Staff_Employee_Num)

<p><strong>Covering Staff Phone Number: </strong>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Covering_Staff_Phone)</p>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Covering_Staff_Phone)

<p><strong>Type Of Time Off: </strong>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type_Of_Time_Off, new SelectList(Model.Types, "Type_ID", "Name"))</p>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type_Of_Time_Off)

<p><strong>Number Of Hours To Be Used: </strong>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hrs_Used)</p>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hrs_Used)
</fieldset>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit this section" /></p>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using such a complicated method, instead you can use the following three lines of code in the function called after your dynamic content is loaded:

```
$("form").removeData("validator");
$("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
```

This will clear out the previous parsed content from the page, allowing all content on the page to be parsed again, and validation to be applied to all elements.

Comment: I tried adding that code at the end of the if statement in the Dupe.js (right after the .find("input") call), as well as at the end of the actual function call in the $(document).ready() section.  In both cases, the text for validation, as well as the coloring of the fields works, but it displays the validation on both fieldsets (the one included in the load, as well as the dynamically added one). On top of that, the form still lets a POST go through even if one of the boxes is left blank.  Thoughts, or do I need to provide more info?  I'm willing to sit here all day until I figure this out.

Comment: Also, I forgot to say, but thank you. I am the only developer at our company, so it is hard to actually bounce ideas off other people.

Comment: Please add your form, as well as what is being cloned.

Comment: Edited initial post to contain form to be cloned.

Comment: Are you also referencing scripts in your `_Layout.cshtml` file?  If not, then there is a problem with the order in which you are adding your scripts, and the order is important.  Also, your design is setting you up for some significant problems regarding accessing the data in your POST action on your controller.  You may be undertaking too complex a task for a single page at your current level.  I would suggest breaking this task into multiple smaller pages.

Comment: I am referencing them in the _Layout.cshtml file.  As for the aformentioned POST problems, I already ran into those.  The whole layout of the site (which I admit is convoluted), was changed in order to accomadate the problems I was having with validation.  Now that I have a reasonable way (your solution) to fix it, I can revert to a better layout.  At the time, I simply didn't understand how to fix my problem, and had to retool the site to reflect my knowledge of the subject.  I will try the other layout, and let you know! Thanks much.